# How to set the port number for SocketConnection in J2ME?

Tags: sockets, java-me, connection, connection-string, port

I want to make a J2ME `SocketConnection` with a computer running Windows XP. The computer's IP address is 192.168.1.28

When creating the connection :

```
SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection)Connector.open("socket://192.168.1.28:portNumber");
```

how to know the value to set for the `portNumber` ?

Comment: what is running in Computer ????? is it on 80 port ?

Comment: a java J2SE program is running in the Computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number can be any 16-bit unsigned integer. It must correspond to the port number used by the service you're connecting to. There are standard ports for various services: 80 for HTTP (web), 25 for SMTP (mail), etc. We can't tell you what port to use without knowing what you're actually connecting to.

Comment: There is a java J2SE program running in the computer , so what is then the port number ? Because my J2ME app will interact with this J2SE program.

Comment: is it running in Apacher or some other web server ?

Comment: The J2SE program gets to choose what port to use. You might need to read the documentation or talk to the developer to find out what port you need to connect to.

Comment: the program starts when the system starts ; I use the "taches planifiées" to start the app with Windows. So I write a batch file (.bat) to launch the java program.

Comment: Google Translate implies "Scheduled Tasks" :)